# unable to overcome the error PAC::ProgramError from my Rails application

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pac

I am new to Ruby. I have written a simple code :
...

```
pac = PAC.load(pacfilename)
return pac.find('http://www.google.com')
```

...

I am using gems

```
gem 'win32-service', '0.8.2', :platforms => :mingw
gem 'pac', "~> 1.0.0"
gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.0beta1', :platforms => :mingw
```

I am getting this following error :
PAC::ProgramError in Accounts#new 
Showing G:/test/app/views/accounts/new.html.erb where line #6 raised:

Cannot call method 'lastIndexOf' of null
Extracted source (around line #6):

3:  >
4: 
5: 
6: <%= getProxyServer %>
7: 
8: <%= link_to 'Back', accounts_path %>

The relevant part of trace file 
pac (1.0.0) lib/pac/runtimes/rubyracer.rb:28:in `rescue in block in call'
pac (1.0.0) lib/pac/runtimes/rubyracer.rb:22:in`block in call'
pac (1.0.0) lib/pac/runtimes/rubyracer.rb:57:in `block in lock'
pac (1.0.0) lib/pac/runtimes/rubyracer.rb:55:in`call'
pac (1.0.0) lib/pac/runtimes/rubyracer.rb:55:in `Locker'
pac (1.0.0) lib/pac/runtimes/rubyracer.rb:55:in`lock'
pac (1.0.0) lib/pac/runtimes/rubyracer.rb:21:in `call'
pac (1.0.0) lib/pac/file.rb:18:in`find'
app/helpers/accounts_helper.rb:46:in `readPACfileData'
app/helpers/accounts_helper.rb:65:in`readPACfile'
app/helpers/accounts_helper.rb:83:in `getProxyServer'

What is the problem? I want to find out the proxyserverIP, if any, programmatically from the  application and then use it for accessing websites. Any help?